# Barcode Generator

Tags: php, barcode, stock, inventory

hi I am developing a online billing software for a Grocery shop .This is a simple application which can be used for to manage their stock and billing .I should integrate bar code generating option in this application . They are using TVS LP45 bacode printer . My plan was to generate barcode to a PDF file and let the user to print that . for example,if  they have 10 units of 1kg onion bag on stock when  they click to generate barcodes for onion we need to get 10 barcode of onion a sheet . I am using PHP  for the implementation .But i am not much idea how to implement  this barcode integration section?  please help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - Thats now what stackoverflow is here and I'm quite sure you won't really get help here, since your question is way too broad.

Comment: https://github.com/picqer/php-barcode-generator this will help you

Answer (score 0):

As you want a solution in PHP, I suggest a simple PHP library called [php-barcode](https://github.com/davidscotttufts/php-barcode/) by [davidscotttufts](http://davidscotttufts.com) .
This is very simple straight forward solution and you may able to generates barcodes in four barcode formats including Code 128, Code 39, Code 2of5, and Codabar.

You can find simple usage in  http://davidscotttufts.com/2009/03/31/how-to-create-barcodes-in-php/